# Using NOT inside queries with order operators in Sphinx

Tags: sphinx

I'm trying to query TermA and TermB in specific order

```
TermA << TermB
```

or sentence

```
TermA SENTENCE TermB
```

But only want them when specific words do NOT occur between them

```
TermA -(NOT1 | NOT2 | NOT3) << TermB
```

But I get the error "NOT cannot be used as before operand"

Essentially trying to find

```
TermA (-A | -B | -C) TermB
```

either inside a sentence or a given proximity e.g.

```
 (TermA (-A | -B | -C) TermB)~10
```

or

```
TermA SENTENCE (-A | -B | -C) SENTENCE TermB
```

But any combination I use fails. Caveat is I am just starting with Sphinx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closest might be

```
(TermA -(NOT1 | NOT2 | NOT3)) << TermB
```

which I think should run.

But might exclude some matches. eg if the document simpley contains NOT1 **anywhere** the document wont match.

I have suggested a negative assertion operator, but nothing has come of it
http://sphinxsearch.com/bugs/view.php?id=1259

---

also linked from that bug report, is the original thread  on the sphinx forum
http://sphinxsearch.com/forum/view.html?id=9869
... I do discuss a workaround I found for that example. I think the same trick might work for you, more thought needed...

Comment: The "NOT1 anywhere in the document" would be a fail for me. I read the forum link thanks my solution right now since I am scanning docs is to do a second pass with the NOTs as part of the term e.g. I do 'Term1 Near/5 Term1' to get all my matches and then do a 'Term1 (BadTerm1 | BadTermN) Term2' and exclude any in the first list that also match the second.

Comment: The problem with doing that, is you might exclude valid matches. You exclude documents that do have the badword phrase, but still have an ok match elsewhere. To do right would need three passs to find documents with both with and without matches!

Comment: Hmm so you mean say if I do '( eat | ate | dined ) NEAR/3 restaurant' to find matches and then ( eat | ate | dined) NEAR/3 (-bad|-awful)) restaurant that would not work? The idea as I see it is to cross-reference IDs that match both passes. If you are saying one of those has both 'dined at my favorite restaurant' AND 'ate at a really bad restaurant' then what would pass 3 do?